# Isn't the tag game-recommendation purely subjective?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm a new user and I have been taking time to read through some rules, set up my account, and just generally get a feel for the sight(I like it a lot btw) So I just got trough reading the Good Subjective, Bad Subjective, and I couldn't help put feel the tag game-recommendation is purely subjective. I mean a recommendation can't really be objective sense most people will recommend different things, and have different opinions about what is being recommended. I did read there is a sister sight purely for the subjective side of things, wouldn't that tag be more fitting there?

Comment: Could you link this mythical sibling?

Comment: In general, not just for game-rec questions, being subjective isn't a problem here so long as it's "Good Subjective." That is, it's backed up either by experience or by citations to another's experience. If a subjective answer comes with experiential evidence that it works for the problem at hand, it's all good. It's just when it's baseless opinion that it's a problem.